# Insert Row and Copy and Paste Values

Tags: vba, excel

I have a "status" type of report that pulls in a from a variety of sources onto a single worksheet. My end goal is to essentially keep a log of each entry. So I created a macro that will copy the range from Sheet8, insert a new row on Sheet11, and then paste the row into Sheet11. Additionally, I added a line to remove the excel selection. 
My issue is the paste is pasting the formula, not the values. **How do have it paste the values of the cells in Sheet8 onto Sheet11?**

```
Sub copyRowToBelow()
On Error GoTo Err_Execute
    Sheet8.Range("A2:L2").Copy
    Sheet11.Range("A2").Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Sheet8.Range("A2:L2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Err_Execute:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then MsgBox "All have been copied!" Else _
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could shift down first, then copy the data by setting the two rows' values equal to one another.

Also, do you mean to only shift one *cell* down? Not that entire row?  My code below shifts the entire row below row 2 down.

```
Sub copyRowToBelow()
On Error GoTo Err_Execute
    Sheet11.Range("A2").Rows("2:2").EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Sheet11.Range("A3:L3").Value = Sheet8.Range("A2:L2").Value

Err_Execute:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then MsgBox "All have been copied!" Else _
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: I did mean the entire row. Can you explain how row 4 actually works? Does that essentially make the range in Sheet11 equal to that data in Sheet8?

Comment: @MaxZ - Yes, doing `Range("A1").Value = Range("B1").Value` gives `A1` the same *values* as `B1`, without any formatting or other change.  This is the same as doing `Range("A1").Copy // Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`